# DATE CONVERSION SCALA

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, scala-collections

I just want to ask if it's possible to convert a string to date without changing it's format?

```
 .withColumn("birthdate",when(col("birthday").isNotNull,to_date(col("birthday"),"MM/dd/YYYY")).otherwise(null))
```

I have a string "01/01/1990" but when I use to_date(col("birthday"),"MM/dd/YYYY"), it becomes **1990-01-01**

Is there any way to convert the string to date without changing it's original format or it is only the format for date datatypes?

Thank you in advanced !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default spark uses `yyyy-MM-dd` format for date type.

if you want to have `MM/dd/YYYY` format as `date type` then its not possible with spark (results null value).

**`Example:`**

**`Converting MM/dd/YYYY to date type:`**

```
scala> spark.sql("select date('01/01/1990') as dt").show()
//+----+
//|  dt|
//+----+
//|null| //result null
//+----+


scala> spark.sql("select date('01/01/1990') as dt").printSchema
//root
 //|-- dt: date (nullable = true)
```

**`Converting YYYY-MM-dd to date type:`**

```
scala> spark.sql("select date('1990-01-01') as dt").show(false)
//+----------+
//|dt        |
//+----------+
//|1990-01-01| //results data
//+----------+


scala> spark.sql("select date('1990-01-01') as dt").printSchema
//root
// |-- dt: date (nullable = true)
```